# workflow timeout functionality not working in aem

Tags: adobe, aem

we are trying to implement timeout for a participant step. But it doesn't seem to be working. When i configure the timeout as immediate, we are able to see the timeout behavior , but when we select the actual time like  1 hr. It is not timing out after the specified time interval. Is there any other configuration that we have to do to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of a bug in com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.job.WorkflowJobUtils as I see. When I set timeout for a Participant step to 1h there is the message in log

```
03.10.2018 16:26:10.681 *DEBUG* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1538573170619] POST /etc/workflow/instances HTTP/1.1] com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.job.WorkflowJobUtils calling createTimeoutJob for workitem /etc/workflow/instances/server0/2018-10-03/test-model_98/workItems/node1_etc_workflow_instances_server0_2018-10-03_test-model_98
03.10.2018 16:26:10.681 *DEBUG* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1538573170619] POST /etc/workflow/instances HTTP/1.1] com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.job.WorkflowJobUtils create timeout event {com.adobe.granite.workflow.console.timeout.job=com.adobe.granite.workflow.job.TimeoutJob@989455c, event.timed.date=Wed Nov 14 08:26:10 MSK 2018, event.timed.id=/etc/workflow/instances/server0/2018-10-03/test-model_98/workItems/node1_etc_workflow_instances_server0_2018-10-03_test-model_98_1538573170632}
```

"event.timed.date=Wed Nov 14 08:26:10 MSK 2018", when the step is assigned to a participant on October 3 at 4 pm. You can add the logger and check from your side, I'm using AEM 6.3. This is the step configuration:

[image: test workflow model]
code from WorkflowJobUtils:

```
Long timeout = (Long)item.getNode().getMetaDataMap().get("timeoutMillis", Long.class);
Date date = calculateDate(timeout.longValue(), addOffset);
props.put("event.timed.date", date);
LOGGER.debug("create timeout event {} ", props);
jobBuilder.properties(props);
List<String> errors = new ArrayList();
ScheduledJobInfo result = jobBuilder.schedule().at(adjustDate(date)).add(errors);

private static Date calculateDate(long seconds, boolean addOffset) {
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  long millies = seconds * 1000L;
  if (addOffset) {
    millies += cal.getTimeInMillis();
  }
  cal.setTimeInMillis(millies);
  return cal.getTime();
}
```

you see in the calculateDate method they expect seconds, but actually for the "1h" option milliseconds are set, 3 600 000. So they multiply it to 1 000 and get 3 600 000 000 millisecond or 3 600 000 seconds, 1 000 hours or 41.6 days.

you can add a new option for the Timeout dropdown here /libs/cq/workflow/components/model/step/tab_common/items/timeout/items/timeout/options as a workaround.

After I added a new option with value "1" there the timeout handler was called:

```
03.10.2018 16:38:54.200 *DEBUG* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1538573934182] POST /etc/workflow/instances HTTP/1.1] com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.job.WorkflowJobUtils calling createTimeoutJob for workitem /etc/workflow/instances/server0/2018-10-03/test-model_99/workItems/node1_etc_workflow_instances_server0_2018-10-03_test-model_99
03.10.2018 16:38:54.201 *DEBUG* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1538573934182] POST /etc/workflow/instances HTTP/1.1] com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.job.WorkflowJobUtils create timeout event {com.adobe.granite.workflow.console.timeout.job=com.adobe.granite.workflow.job.TimeoutJob@267dc5f3, event.timed.date=Wed Oct 03 16:38:55 MSK 2018, event.timed.id=/etc/workflow/instances/server0/2018-10-03/test-model_99/workItems/node1_etc_workflow_instances_server0_2018-10-03_test-model_99_1538573934194} 
03.10.2018 16:38:59.335 *INFO* [sling-oak-observation-212] org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.JobQueueImpl.Granite Workflow Timeout Queue Starting job queue Granite Workflow Timeout Queue
03.10.2018 16:38:59.336 *INFO* [sling-oak-observation-212] org.apache.sling.event Service [QueueMBean for queue Granite Workflow Timeout Queue,14915, [org.apache.sling.event.jobs.jmx.StatisticsMBean]] ServiceEvent REGISTERED
03.10.2018 16:38:59.435 *DEBUG* [sling-threadpool-7e90cbd1-c78f-4aff-add9-eba2c792e8fe-(apache-sling-job-thread-pool)-22-Granite Workflow Timeout Queue(com/adobe/granite/workflow/timeout/job)] com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.job.TimeoutHandler process timeout job for event JobImpl [properties=org.apache.sling.api.wrappers.ValueMapDecorator@136322bc : {slingevent:application=fa67a921-cc59-4097-953a-a6e69ff5b718, jcr:created=java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1538573939311,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=false,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT+03:00",offset=10800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2018,MONTH=9,WEEK_OF_YEAR=40,WEEK_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_MONTH=3,DAY_OF_YEAR=276,DAY_OF_WEEK=4,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=1,HOUR=4,HOUR_OF_DAY=16,MINUTE=38,SECOND=59,MILLISECOND=311,ZONE_OFFSET=10800000,DST_OFFSET=0], event.timed.date=Wed Oct 03 16:38:55 MSK 2018, slingevent:created=java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1538573939203,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=false,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT+03:00",offset=10800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2018,MONTH=9,WEEK_OF_YEAR=40,WEEK_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_MONTH=3,DAY_OF_YEAR=276,DAY_OF_WEEK=4,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=1,HOUR=4,HOUR_OF_DAY=16,MINUTE=38,SECOND=59,MILLISECOND=203,ZONE_OFFSET=10800000,DST_OFFSET=0], event.job.queuename=Granite Workflow Timeout Queue, event.job.queued.time=java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1538573939203,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=false,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT+03:00",offset=10800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2018,MONTH=9,WEEK_OF_YEAR=40,WEEK_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_MONTH=3,DAY_OF_YEAR=276,DAY_OF_WEEK=4,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=1,HOUR=4,HOUR_OF_DAY=16,MINUTE=38,SECOND=59,MILLISECOND=203,ZONE_OFFSET=10800000,DST_OFFSET=0], jcr:createdBy=sling-event, sling:resourceType=slingevent:Job, slingevent:eventId=2018/10/3/16/38/fa67a921-cc59-4097-953a-a6e69ff5b718_92, event.timed.id=/etc/workflow/instances/server0/2018-10-03/test-model_99/workItems/node1_etc_workflow_instances_server0_2018-10-03_test-model_99_1538573934194, event.job.application=fa67a921-cc59-4097-953a-a6e69ff5b718, event.job.retries=10, com.adobe.granite.workflow.console.timeout.job=com.adobe.granite.workflow.job.TimeoutJob@29a9a2f7, event.job.started.time=java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1538573939376,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/Minsk",offset=10800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=69,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2018,MONTH=9,WEEK_OF_YEAR=40,WEEK_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_MONTH=3,DAY_OF_YEAR=276,DAY_OF_WEEK=4,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=1,HOUR=4,HOUR_OF_DAY=16,MINUTE=38,SECOND=59,MILLISECOND=376,ZONE_OFFSET=10800000,DST_OFFSET=0], jcr:primaryType=slingevent:Job, event.job.retrycount=0, :sling:jobs:asynchandler=org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.JobConsumerManager$JobConsumerWrapper$1@8f1e51d, event.job.topic=com/adobe/granite/workflow/timeout/job}, topic=com/adobe/granite/workflow/timeout/job, path=/var/eventing/jobs/assigned/fa67a921-cc59-4097-953a-a6e69ff5b718/com.adobe.granite.workflow.timeout.job/2018/10/3/16/38/fa67a921-cc59-4097-953a-a6e69ff5b718_92, jobId=2018/10/3/16/38/fa67a921-cc59-4097-953a-a6e69ff5b718_92]
03.10.2018 16:38:59.443 *DEBUG* [sling-threadpool-7e90cbd1-c78f-4aff-add9-eba2c792e8fe-(apache-sling-job-thread-pool)-22-Granite Workflow Timeout Queue(com/adobe/granite/workflow/timeout/job)] com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.job.TimeoutHandler process timeout job for work item /etc/workflow/instances/server0/2018-10-03/test-model_99/workItems/node1_etc_workflow_instances_server0_2018-10-03_test-model_99


03.10.2018 16:38:59.701 *INFO* [sling-threadpool-7e90cbd1-c78f-4aff-add9-eba2c792e8fe-(apache-sling-job-thread-pool)-22-Granite Workflow Timeout Queue(com/adobe/granite/workflow/timeout/job)] etc.workflow.scripts.test-timeout-handler$ecma 
Test timeout handler /etc/workflow/scripts/test-timeout-handler.ecma is called
```